# How to add strings without any problems using parallel foreach?

Tags: c#, string, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Here is my current code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Arguments, Argument =>
{
    if (Argument != Command_Name)
    {
        WebRequest web_request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.aol.com/?command=1&domain=" + Argument);
        web_request.Timeout = 5000;
        ((HttpWebRequest)web_request).UserAgent = "Mozilla Firefox 5.0";
        HttpWebResponse web_response = (HttpWebResponse)web_request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader response = new StreamReader(web_response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        Message += Argument + " => " + response.ReadToEnd() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
});
```

This code does not work correctly, I am looking for a SMALL alternative that does. This code returns some of the arguments in the Message string... What is a good way to multi-threaded string addition? That is what I need.

More info: The Message string will return a, b, and c sometimes while others it will only return just a or b...

I appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging the current behavior using your IDE to see why this occurs?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong when I debug it, no errors or anything. When I use a normal for each though, it works. It is just with the threading for some reason...

Comment: use a thread safe collection. store the messages inside of it then concatenate them after the loop.

Comment: Can you show me an example? @Selman22

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a thread-safe collection to store the messages such as [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).Then just make the concetanation after the loop:

```
var messages = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(Arguments, Argument =>
{
   ... 
   messages.Add(Argument + " => " + response.ReadToEnd());
}
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, messages);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just lock around the `Message +=` part:

```
//scoped to the same scope as the Message object
private Object thisLock = new Object();

var textResult = response.ReadToEnd() + Environment.NewLine;
lock(thisLock)
{
    Message += Argument + " => " + textResult;
}
```

Comment: if we use lock statement then we need to sacrifice multi threading speed i assume...what u say?

Comment: Yes, but given this is in the context of making multiple web requests, I would expect the lock overhead to be relatively insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

for collect elements `AsParallel()` its more appropriate:

```
var lines = Arguments.AsParallel().Select(Argument =>
{
    if (Argument == Command_Name) return null;

    WebRequest web_request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.aol.com/?command=1&domain=" + Argument);
    web_request.Timeout = 5000;
    ((HttpWebRequest)web_request).UserAgent = "Mozilla Firefox 5.0";
    HttpWebResponse web_response = (HttpWebResponse)web_request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader response = new StreamReader(web_response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

    return Argument + " => " + response.ReadToEnd();
}).ToArray();

var concate = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [concurrent collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) and make that afterwards to one string

```
var ThreadSafeList = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<string>();
Parallel.ForEach(Arguments, Argument =>
{
    if (Argument != Command_Name)
    {
        WebRequest web_request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.aol.com/?command=1&domain=" + Argument);
        web_request.Timeout = 5000;
        ((HttpWebRequest)web_request).UserAgent = "Mozilla Firefox 5.0";
        HttpWebResponse web_response = (HttpWebResponse)web_request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader response = new StreamReader(web_response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        ThreadSafeList.Add(Argument + " => " + response.ReadToEnd());                    
    }
});
string Result = string.Join("", ThreadSafeList);
```

Or try to lock the Item you want to write.

```
StringBuilder Message = new StringBuilder();
Parallel.ForEach(Arguments, Argument =>
{
    if (Argument != Command_Name)
    {
        WebRequest web_request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.aol.com/?command=1&domain=" + Argument);
        web_request.Timeout = 5000;
        ((HttpWebRequest)web_request).UserAgent = "Mozilla Firefox 5.0";
        HttpWebResponse web_response = (HttpWebResponse)web_request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader response = new StreamReader(web_response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        lock(Message) //locking here
        {
           Message.AppendLine(Argument + " => " + response.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, or is working for me so far. Thanks! Let me keep testing, if confirmed I will accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Implementing thread safety in this case wuold probably best involve the [`lock` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). Remember never to lock on an object you don't have exclusive access to, which in this case cabe method-scoped.

```
object key = new object(); // Empty object serves lightest for locks
Parallel.ForEach(Arguments, Argument =>
{
    if (Argument != Command_Name)
    {
        WebRequest web_request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.aol.com/?command=1&domain=" + Argument);
        web_request.Timeout = 5000;
        ((HttpWebRequest)web_request).UserAgent = "Mozilla Firefox 5.0";
        HttpWebResponse web_response = (HttpWebResponse)web_request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader response = new StreamReader(web_response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);

        lock(key)
            Message += Argument + " => " + response.ReadToEnd() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
});
```